# How do you tokenise / tokenize / split a delimited string in Perl?

Tags: perl, split, token

How do you split a string e.g. "a:b:c:d" into tokens for parsing in Perl?

(e.g. using split?)

Looking for clear, straightforward answer above all (but do add any interesting tidbits of info afterwards).

Comment: Didn't you take the time to read `man perlfunc`? There are even examples there! E.g.: `print join(':', split(/,/, 'a,b,c,,,')), "\n";`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is what you want.

```
@tokens = split(/:/, "a:b:c:d");
foreach my $token (@tokens) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: foreach my $token (@tokens) {}
my! my! my :)

Comment: What if you want to tokenize a string containing a simple mathematical expression and also need to account for the fact that mathematical operators may be attached directly to an operand without any space to separate them? For instance 'x= 3*2' ... is there a way (other than multiple calls to split with different separator sequences) to get each operand and operator returned as a separate token?

Comment: Nevermind, apparently there is (lifted from perldoc):

split(/(-)|(,)/, "1-10,20", 3) -> ('1', '-', undef, '10', undef, ',', '20')

Answer (score 9):

You can use split. You can also use it with a regex.

```
my @tokens = split(/:/,$string);
```

For more advanced parsing, I recommend [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-RecDescent/)

Comment: Note that split() also takes a string as the first parameter, which is more effecient in the cases like this where it's just a simple string. split(':', $string)

Comment: @mpeters: No, it is still a regex. try split ".", "ab.cd"; "." matches any character. And using the string " " consisting of a single space is a special case, which does not mean "match a single space"

Comment: @mpeters: What split lets you do is use quotes (single or double) for regex delimiters without the preceding "m" as the usual regex operator.

Comment: V good and simple, going to take the foreach answer as that's very handy for beginners.

Answer (score 5):

Also take a look at the documentation that comes with perl by typing at a command line prompt:

```
perldoc -f split
```

To search the FAQs use

```
perldoc -q split
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have:

```
$a = "a:b:c:d";
@b = split /:/, $a;
```

then you get:

```
@b = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

In general, this is how split works:

```
split /PATTERN/,EXPR
```

Where `PATTERN` can be pretty much regex.  You're not limited to simple tokens like '`:`'